# Creating an across-the-board discount price based on one attribute

Tags: attributes

On our Magento site at http://www.onos.com, we are needing to quickly provide a discounted sales price all sunglasses that offer the Lens Color Option of Green Mirror over Amber lenses from the ONOS Sunglasses Category.  We are going to offer any frame with this particular "Green Mirror over Amber" lens for a price like $59.95.  What is going to be the easiest way to create this discount?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with a **promotion cart rule**:

1. Create a promotion cart rule
2. Right there go to **Conditions Tab** and click **Green plus Button**
3. Select Product attribute combination thi is going to appear
   "If an item is FOUND  in the cart with TODOS  of these conditions true: "
4. Again Click **Green plus button** and in that list select your Attritube Color in this case **Green Mirror over Amber**
5. after that just fill out all other tabs and save Rule.

if you need more details.. just ask me.